# How to keep an iOS app process run always though the user has terminated the app and check for device location in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, cllocationmanager

I need to check for device location every one hour or so and if the location is outside a particular area ( say the device has been taken out of the office premises ), do some action (like show a local notification saying "Hey! The device is outside the office").

To do this, I need to keep checking for location every one hour even though the app is killed. How to keep the app stay alive like forever though it has been terminated by the user.

Comment: iOS doesn't support true multitasking,so i dnt think so this will work on iOS device

Comment: @AkashShinde: Read on and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. The best way do this is to use **Geofencing**.

It uses startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region where we provide the latitude and longitude of the centre of the region and also the radius of the region.

When the device moves into this region, didEnterRegion gets called.
When the device moves out of this region, didExitRegion gets called.

And yes **it works even when the app is terminated/backgrounded.**

In addition, we have to set NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in the App's Info.plist file which you will find under the Supporting Files.

View this article for detailed information.
http://www.devfright.com/how-to-use-the-clregion-class-for-geofencing/

Inorder to test this in a simulator, I used local notifications when it enters and exits the region using UILocalNotification in the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods.

```
`UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:1];
notification.alertBody = @"You have entered the region";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];`
```

Now change the custom location of the iOS simulator (Debug -> Location -> Custom Location), and provide latitude and longitude within the region and you get a notification saying "You have entered the region" and change the custom location to latitude and longitude outside the region, you will get a notification saying "You have exited the region".

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it but if your system is deployment target is greater then 7.0.

In ios7.1 there is method called [startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges). This method updates location in background and even if application is terminated as per apple document:

> Starts the generation of updates based on significant location changes.
>
> If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the
>   system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new
>   event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the
>   application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods of your app
>   delegate contains the key UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey to
>   indicate that your app was launched because of a location event. Upon
>   relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call
>   this method to continue receiving location events. When you restart
>   location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate
>   immediately. In addition, the location property of your location
>   manager object is populated with the most recent location object even
>   before you start location services.

I found one demo for this may this help you. look this link http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

Comment: i edit my answer and i put one link which may help you. Happy coading

Comment: `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is available from iOS4.0. Then why you are saying deployment target should be grater than 8?

Comment: i have put a link in that reason is written which is following
Apple does not communicate much with the developers on the ways to do that. If you remember this post from early 2014: Apple’s iOS 7.1 will fix a geolocation bug — after developer sends letter to Tim Cook. In iOS 7.0, Apple prevents the location update when the app is killed/terminated/suspended. But, Apple has fixed the “bug” starting from iOS 7.1 by allowing the app to get the location coordinates.

Comment: So are you trying to say that it will work from iOS 7.1? which again contradicts with your answer.

Comment: @AnilVarghese thanks for your suggestion about that point and i found that  you are right you should used it in ios7.1 Sorry about above answer. I edit that things